# Do i need to check db null or any other null when fetching data from sql server in ado.net?

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[StoredProcedureName]"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "20";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "5";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = db.SelectQry(cmd))
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {
                            int returnValue;
                            int.TryParse(dr["count"].ToString(), out countDealerOfTheMonthCars);
                            usedCarModel.DealerOfTheMonth.CountDealerOfTheMonthCars = countDealerOfTheMonthCars;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I noticed people have placed checks like (dr["count"] != DBNull.Value) then only do dr["count"].ToString().

But i noticed that even DBNull.Value.ToString() in an empty string in C#. So my question is do we need to have any such db null or null checks or we can directly do:
int.TryParse(dr["count"].ToString(), out count);

Comment: But what are you doing in that stored procedure? Something in your code suggests that you are performing a SELECT COUNT(*) on your data.

Answer (score 1):

Either way you are performing a defensive check. If the column can be null (i.e, the column is a nullable column) then do perform a a null check and programming `null` is different from `DBNull` and so better to check for `DBNull` saying `dr["count"] != DBNull.Value`.

With `TryParse()` also you are kind a performing the same thing since `TryParse()` as name suggest doesn't directly throw an exception upon failure rather results in `true/false`.

I would rather check for column nullability and perform calculation on that column accordingly.

Comment: why should i check in my scenario as if its null and i do dbnull.value.ToString(), it gives me empty string which is fine with me. So i think checking != DBNull.Value before doing .ToString() is unnecessary.

Comment: @sahil, NO, check for `DBNull.Value` and not `DBNull.Value.ToString()`

Comment: ok. But i want to know the reason. Why would i put extra check of DBNull.Value when i can do dr["count"].ToString() without exception even if dr["count"] has null value in database.

Comment: @sahil, Yes you can but as said earlier it's a defensive check and so if the column returned value is null then you don't perform the action. In your case it's just `ToString()` but it could be sending that column to a method which is computationally expensive and so you get rid of the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is true, how do you differentiate an empty string from DBNull, if you don't check for DBNull ?
It's might be not apply in your case, but an empty string IS NOT DBNull !